# Collatz sequence vs A180076 (OEIS)

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I found a sequence in OEIS ([A180076](https://oeis.org/A180076)) where a subsection is similar (but not entirely) to trajectory of $27$ in Collatz function. In the comments section I read: *"Permutation of the natural numbers with inverse A180077;"*

Here is a slice of the sequence

$\{ \mathbf{27}, 82, 41, 124, 31, 94, 47, 142, 71, 214, \mathbf{53},...\}$

But if I start with 27 of the formal collatz function:

$\{ \mathbf{27}, 82, 41, 124, \mathbf{62}, 31, 94, 47, 142, 71, 214, \mathbf{71},...\}$

How is the (topmost sequence) permutation generated? I found it hard to understand how it works by that page. I see there is one missing number ($62$) in that sequence and the last value is also different. Seems the last value is divided by $2$ when it is odd. It is of curiousity that looks so similar to a sequence that i supposed to be a permutation of the natural numbers with inverse. Is it because of the $3n+1$ formula that these are similar? Also what are the similarities by this sequence and the sequence generated by:

$f(n)=\{3n+1 \}\quad \text{if odd or} \quad \{n/2\} \quad \text{if even} $ ?

Comment: It literally states how it's generated. look at the binary representation of a(n), find the least number not in the sequence already that is in it. If you can't find one that isn't there, multiply a(n) by 3 and add 1.

Comment: You also don't get 71,214,71 in collatz.